# Kubernetes ingress for Teamcity blank page

Tags: linux, kubernetes, teamcity, haproxy

I have problem whit a ingress. I'm using haproxy, but after apply yaml file(s) I'm not able to open teamcity site in web browser. I got blank page. If I use curl it shows nothing.
Test echo (image: jmalloc/echo-server) is working just fine.
Of course kubernetes.local is added to hosts file to be able to resolve DNS name.

My config yaml files:

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: teamcity
  name: teamcity
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: teamcity
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: teamcity
    spec:
      tolerations:
      - key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
        effect: NoExecute
        tolerationSeconds: 10
      - key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
        effect: NoExecute
        tolerationSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - image: jetbrains/teamcity-server
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: teamcity
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8111
        volumeMounts:
        - name: teamcity-pvc-data
          mountPath: "/data/teamcity_server/datadir"
        - name: teamcity-pvc-logs
          mountPath: "/opt/teamcity/logs"
      volumes:
      - name: teamcity-pvc-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: teamcity-pvc-data
      - name: teamcity-pvc-logs
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: teamcity-pvc-logs

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    run: teamcity
  name: teamcity
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    haproxy.org/check: "true"
    haproxy.org/forwarded-for: "true"
    haproxy.org/load-balance: "roundrobin"
spec:
  selector:
    run: teamcity
  ports:
  - name: port-tc
    port: 8111
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8111
  externalIPs:
    - 192.168.22.152
    - 192.168.22.153   

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: teamcity
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: kubernetes.local
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /teamcity
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: teamcity
            port:
              number: 8111
```

I wold be grateful for every hint. Struggling whit this for hours. connection to http://192.168.22.152:8111 is working fine too. Just Ingress having troubles.

Answer (score 0):

subdomain is fixing problem teamcity.kubernetes.local kubernetes.local/teamcity doesn't work.

Solution:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: teamcity-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: teamcity.kubernetes.local
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: teamcity
            port:
              number: 8111
```